# Trying to extract field from browser page

Tags: linux

I'm trying to extract one field from Firefox to my local Ubuntu 12.04 PC and Mac OS 19.7.4 from an online form

I can manually save the page locally as a text document and then search for the text using Unix script but this seems rather cumbersome & I require it to be automated. Is there another more efficient method?

My background is on Macs but the company is trialling Linux PC's, so please be tolerant of my relevant Ubuntu ignorance.

Comment: Note sure from your description what you are actually trying to do. But it sounds like you try to process some (html) form you get from a http request? Well then take a look at `cURL` or `wget`, they allow to 'download' the form. And they can be invoked from any scripting language, for example a bash shell. Such script can also process a file downloaded right before...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to program something try

- WWW:Mechanize library, it have  python and perl bindings,
- several mousescripting engines in lunux, (actionaz)
- test automation tool which works with firefox (Selenium)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simple BASH script.
Take a look at some useful stuff like:

- wget
- sed
- grep

and then nothing will by cumbersome and everything can go automatic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with the method that you mentioned, you can use [curl](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_curl.htm) to automate the saving of the form.  Your BASH script would then look something like this:

```
curl http://locationofonlineform.com -o tempfile
valueOfField=$(grep patternToFindField tempfile)
// Do stuff
echo $valueOfField
```

If you want to get rid of the temporary file, you can directly feed the result of curl into the grep command.